How to solve eroor while Generating path profile in Global Mapper?
GENERATE_PATH_PROFILE \
FILENAME="D:\Dem\profile.xyz" \
ELEV_UNITS=METERS \
POINT_SPACING=10.0 \
START_POS= 338150.4, 2434693.7 \
END_POS=338996.5, 2433865.5
APPEND_TO_FILE=YES \
SAVE_DIST_Z_FILE=YES \
This code when I run in global mapper giving an error
WARNING: Unknown parameter <338150.4>ignored for GENERATE_PATH_PROFILE command.
Unable to get coordinate for GENERATE_PATH_PROFILE command from value 'YES'.
How to fix this error?
